# Does jar file not contain imported packages and classes?

Tags: java, import, jar

I tried a simple A package B package example.

Package structure is like this -

```
---A
     |---a.class
---B
     |---b.class
```

a.class imports package B and class b.

Then I created a jar file with the following command -

```
jar -cvf a.jar A
```

Then I displayed the contents of the jar file using "jar -tf a.jar" command, and I see the following -

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
A/
A/a.class
```

How come B/b.class is not a part of the jar file when A/a.class imports it?

Also how does A/a.class run correctly with B/b.class being a part of it?

```
java -cp ./A.jar A.a
```

Comment: Tried this and it worked. I was also wondering why when I run the a.class through “java -cp ./a.jar A.a” command and even though I had created a reference of B.b (just created a new object, did not do anything else), it does not give any runtime error of B.b not found. 

Only when I actually called a method on B.b and ran again through same command above it gave me a runtime error. 

Seemed like JVM allowed creating a reference without any issues even though B.b was not included in a.jar…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `import` statement allows you to refer to a class that's in another package by its short name; it does nothing else. `import`s aren't even carried over to the compiled `.class` file; all references are replaced by fully-qualified names.